# What are the large .f136 and .f171 files in my Downloads folder?

Tags: macos

Today I discovered two large files in my Downloads folder:

```
$ ls -laht
total 19283784
-rw-r--r--@  1 mmorin  staff   6.0K  9 Sep 11:39 .DS_Store
drwx------+ 11 mmorin  staff   352B  9 Sep 11:39 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 65 mmorin  staff   2.0K  2 Sep 09:43 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 mmorin  staff   495M 25 Sep  2018 .f171
-rw-r--r--   1 mmorin  staff   8.7G 24 Sep  2018 .f136
-rw-------   1 mmorin  staff     0B 29 Jan  2018 .localized
```

They haven't been modified in one year. A `cat` of `.f171` showed it was a binary file. I removed both files and the available space on the computer did not increase by 9.2 gigabytes immediately as I expected but it did after a day. I can recover them from a backup if needed.

What are these files?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following comment on Reddit.

> tl;dr you need to add ffmpeg or avconv executables to your PATH Sounds
>   less like a problem with youtube-dl and more like you do not have
>   ffmpeg or avconv on your PATH. Without one of the two, the streams
>   cannot be muxed into a single file, so you're winding up with two
>   files named .f136 and .f251 then you have a separate audio and video
>   files, where you probably just want the single file with both audio
>   and video streams contained in MP4/MKV/WEBM.

and,

> They are separate audio and video files. You don't have ffmpeg
>   installed and working, so it can't merge them into a single file.
>   Install ffmpeg and make sure to add it to your path (google how to do
>   this).

I cannot find anything about a .f171 file.

Comment: I now have `ffmpeg` in my PATH but maybe I didn't last year when those files were created.

Comment: Can you add the link to the Reddit thread?

Comment: @miguelmorin I don't remember the references.  I'd have to start over and then I don't know how to post a link on Reddit...

Comment: OK, thanks. If the Reddit discussion is private, then I don't know how to post the link either.